# Ng-model and ng-repeat to populate dynamic input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i am totally new to AngularJS framework.
Previously i used raw Javascript and JQuery
I am integrating it in my Laravel App.

How do i achieve dynamically adding multiple input field which is under a set, using ng-model and ng-repeat and only execute when user input / keyup on any of the last set of added field?

```
    <div class="form-group row">
           <div class="chargable-group" ng-repeat="">

                 <div class="col-md-3">
                       <label class="form-control-label" for="l2" id="chargable-label">Chargable Item</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-9" id="chargable-header">
                          <textarea name="chargable[]" class="form-control dynamic chargable" id="chargable-1"> </textarea>
                          <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.01" name="chargable-price-1">
                          <input type="number" class="form-control" name="chargable-quantity-1">
                          <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.01" name="chargable-total-1">
                 </div>

           </div>
     </div>
```

Is the code structure is like above?
And where should i start?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

one way that you can do it is pass **$last** in keyup function call at controller and detect is $last is null or not. if not null then it is last element :

```
 <textarea name="chargable[]" class="form-control dynamic chargable" id="chargable-1" ng-keyup="callMe($last)"> </textarea>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.callMe = function(last){ 
  if(last){
    //code if it is last
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, when You want add dynamic multiple element for Your DOM just add ng-repeat in interested DOM element. For example:

and in 'item' You have access to each row in Your 'itemsArray'

Comment: how do i detect keyup and based on keyup on the last dynamically populated textarea, only populate another set?